Question regarding generating function.
In my text book there's an example (Please see image attached) related to generating functions which uses quadratic formula to get the roots then it's transformed into a form which I can't get my head around, to be specific I don't understand how the denominator went from (x - r1)(x - r2) to (1 - a1x)(1 - a2x), any help would be much appreciated.
Click to see image

The solution probably could have explained this better. What is happening here is the following: We have the denominator
$-(x-r_{1})(x-r_{2})$
From it, it's possible to factor out $-r_{1}$ and $-r_{2}$, obtaining:
$-(-r_{1})(1-x/r_{1})(-r_{2})(1-x/r_{2}) = r_{1}r_{2}(1-x/r_{1})(1-x/r_{2})$
However, we know the original equation (and it's roots) and can clearly tell that $r_{1}r_{2}=-1$ (since they are roots of $-x^{2}-x+1=0$, so vietas formulas clearly give $r_{1}r_{2}=-1$), so we end up with
$(1-x/r_{1})(1-x/r_{2})$
Which can be written as
$(1-\alpha_{1}x)(1-\alpha_{2}x)$
Where $\alpha_{1} = \frac{1}{r_{1}}$ and $\alpha_{2}=\frac{1}{r_{2}}$
If you do these computations yourself you will see that the $\alpha$ I describe are exactly the ones given by the solution you linked.

Thanks for your reply. Why does the product of r1 and r2 equal to 1? and in my text book a1 and a2 equal to 1 +/- square root of 5 / 2 (sorry for typing using letters, I'm still trying to figure out how to type maths notations on stackexchange)

sorry it should have been $-1$. Fixed

Could you please explain why the product of r1 and r2 is 1/-1? and please explain why your value of a1 and a2 are different from the example in my textbook?

You have the values. Just compute the product.

Or you can use the well known fact that for any $ax^2 + bx + c=0$, the product of it's roots is $c/a$. Which in our case, where $-x^{2}-x+1=0$, means the product of the roots (r1r2) is $1/-1 = -1$

As for $\alpha_{1}$ and $\alpha_{2}$ they are simply inverted. My $\alpha_{1}$ is your textbooks $\alpha_{2}$ and vice versa. It doesn't change the expression

I see your point and thanks for pointing this out, looks like I need to brush up on some algebra

There is a misprint in the textbook. Should be $$1-x-x^2=-(x-r_1)(x-r_2)=r_1r_2(1-x/r_1)(1-x/r_2)$$ The minus sign is missing there in the first equality. That's why you have encountered a problem.

Huh that's true. And here I tought I was the one who missed a minus sign when I edited my answer

could you please explain why there's a minus sign in the front?

it's due to the polynomial factorization. Any polynomial $a_{n}x^{n}+\dots+a_{0}$ can be written as $a_{n}(x-r_{1})(x-r_{2})\dots(x-r_{n})$ where $r_{1},\dots,r_{n}$ are the roots of this polynomial. In our case, we have $a_{n}=-1$ since our polynomial is $-x^{2}-x+1$

@Almeida that made a lot of sense, thank you :)
